# How to ask f.write() to put NA's if there is no data in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My goal is to scrape some specific data on multiple profile pages on khan academy. And put the data on a csv file.

Here is the code to scrape one specific profile page and put it on a csv:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/DFletcher1990/')
r.html.render(sleep=5)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')

user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')

dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]

user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')

data = {}
for gettext in user_socio_table:
   category = gettext.find('span')
   category_text = category.text.strip()
   number = category.previousSibling.strip()
   data[category_text] = number

filename = "khanscraptry1.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "date, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx\n"
f.write(headers)
f.write(dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "\n")
f.close()
```

This code is working fine with this specific link(`'https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/DFletcher1990/'`).

Now though when I change my link to an other profile on khan academy for example : `'https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Kkasparas/'`

I get this error :

`KeyError: 'project help requests'`

This is normal because on this profile `"https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Kkasparas/"` there is no `project help requests` value (and no `project help replies` either).

Thus `data['project help requests']` and `data['project help replies']` don't exist and thus can't be written on the csv file.

My goal is to run this script with many profile pages.
So I would like to know how to put an `NA` in every case I will not get the data on each variable. And then print te `NA`'s to the csv file.

In other words : I would like to make my script work for any kind of user profile page.

Many thanks in advance for your contributions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a new list with all possible headers and set the value of keys that are not present to 'NA', before writing it to the file.

```
full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks']
for header_value in full_data_keys:
    if header_value not in data.keys():
        data[header_value]='NA'
```

Also  gentle reminder to provide a fully working code in your question. `user_socio_table` was not defined in the question. I had to look up your previous question to get that.

Full code would be

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/Kkasparas/')
r.html.render(sleep=5)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.html.html,'html.parser')
user_info_table=soup.find('table', class_='user-statistics-table')
dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
data = {}
user_socio_table=soup.find_all('div', class_='discussion-stat')
for gettext in user_socio_table:
   category = gettext.find('span')
   category_text = category.text.strip()
   number = category.previousSibling.strip()
   data[category_text] = number
full_data_keys=['questions','votes','answers','flags raised','project help requests','project help replies','comments','tips and thanks']
for header_value in full_data_keys:
    if header_value not in data.keys():
        data[header_value]='NA'
filename = "khanscraptry1.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "date, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx\n"
f.write(headers)
f.write(dates + "," + points.replace("," , "") + "," + videos + "," + data['questions'] + "," + data['votes'] + "," + data['answers'] + "," + data['flags raised'] + "," + data['project help requests'] + "," + data['project help replies'] + "," + data['comments'] + "," + data['tips and thanks'] + "\n")
f.close()
```

Ouput - khanscraptry1.csv

```
date, points, videos, questions, votes, answers, flags, project_request, project_replies, comments, tips_thx
6 years ago,1527829,1123,25,100,2,0,NA,NA,0,0
```

Change to the following lines if user_info_table is not present

```
if user_info_table is not None:
    dates,points,videos=[tr.find_all('td')[1].text for tr in user_info_table.find_all('tr')]
else:
    dates=points=videos='NA'
```

Comment: Thank you very much (I corrected the code). You manage to put NA's on the user_socio_table aspect. How can you do the same but on user_info_table ? Do you treat it like a list too ? Let's say with this profile for example : ```https://www.khanacademy.org/profile/kaid_469713933603252186458635/```

Comment: @RobZ The user_info_table is None as there is no such table in that page. I have edited the answer to include the change.